# edit profile data flutter with token bearer from SharedPreferences

Tags: api, flutter, dart, postman, bearer-token

I have created a login feature using Postman token bearer which allows users to stay logged in even though the application has been closed.
And now I want to edit the email and profile password that has been logged into the application and then save it with the same token bearer from the saved sharpref.

how to implement it. below is my code to get the data but this code still has an error.

```
getPerfs() async {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
var apikey = prefs.getString('apikey');
print(apikey);
}

var url = 'http://api.batulimee.com/v1_ship/my_profile';
Future<Map> getData() async {
var fullUrl = url + await getPerfs();
var response = await http.post(fullUrl);
return json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
}
```

and this is json structure from the API url my_profile.

```
{
"status": "success",
"data": {
    "id_user": 49,
    "id_role": "8",
    "name_role": "Ship Owner",
    "first_name": "a",
    "last_name": "f",
    "email": "afriansyahm86@gmail.com",
    "phone": "082258785595",
    "saldo": "0",
    "company_name": "aa",
    "company_address": "jl kav pgri",
    "photo": "https://batulimee.com/foto_user/avatar.png"
},
"message": "get profile detail successfully "
```

}

which if you want to get it, you have to use the Postman authorization token bearer.

[image: which if you want to get it, you have to use the Postman authorization token bearer.]

how to get all of this data and edit it?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is in your getPerfs() method, I can see you are saving apikey but that is not accessible to other methods which getData() in your case.

I would do this bit differently,

```
      Future<Map<String,dynamic>> getData() async {

       try {
         var url = 'http://api.batulimee.com/v1_ship/my_profile';
       
          SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
          
          var apikey = prefs.getString('apikey');
          
          var response = await http.post(
            url,
            headers: {
              "Accept": "application/json",
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              "Bearer Token" : apikey
        
            },
          );
       var checkResponse =  json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
       print('checkResponse');
       return checkResponse;  
        } catch (e) {
          print(e);
          throw(e); 
        }
      }
```

Just copy and paste this code and you will get your data, but I would recommend you to save your fetched data in a variable instead of returning data.

One more thing, this could be a get API instead of post API because you are giving nothing in the request payload.

Comment: but I provide a variable token bearer

Comment: @Aphron you are creating apikey variable which is accessible to getPerfs() method only you cannot use that variable in getData() method. If you want to use use apikey then declare it under Class not in a method.

Comment: im sorry Shrey Jain, i was update my post. pls take a look. To get the json data from my_profile, requires a token bearer which must be specified in the Authorization parameter like in the picture.

Comment: That token bearer is the same as the token that was generated when I logged in. then I save it on sharedperf so that the user remains logged in. then the token bearer can also be used to get json data from my_profile

Comment: Hi @Aphron sorry for the late reply, var fullUrl = url + await getPerfs(); , this is wrong implementation, async/await thing takes time, so there can be chances where in ur fullUrl variable u do not have apikey attached with ur URL, second thing in your getPerfs() u r not returning anything so var fullUrl = url;  this will be case always.